# Invalid value 'armeabi'

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-mac

I get this error message when I want to (re)build my project:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3):
>   Error XA0115: Invalid value 'armeabi' in $(AndroidSupportedAbis). This
>   ABI is no longer supported. Please update your project properties to
>   remove the old value. If the properties page does not show an
>   'armeabi' checkbox, un-check and re-check one of the other ABIs and
>   save the changes. (XA0115) (MonoGame.Framework.Android)

I have already changed my Android build settings in Visual Studio, but it still doesn't work with the new settings. I use macOS Catalina and Visual Studio for Mac Community 8.3.6 (build 4).

Why is it not working?

Current build settings:
[image]

Comment: Check your csproj if it still contains `armeabi` in `<AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi;armeabi-v7a;arm64-v8a</AndroidSupportedAbis>`

Comment: It still contains the line <AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;arm64-v8a</AndroidSupportedAbis> and I still get the same error message.